# How is C++ function's default parameter passed?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

Say I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int defaultvalue[] = {1,2};
int fun(int * arg = defaultvalue)
{
    arg[0] += 1;
    return arg[0];
}

int main()
{
   cout << fun() << endl;
   cout << fun() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

and the result is:

```
2
3
```

which make sense because the pointer `*arg` manipulated the array `defaultvalue`. However, if I changed the code into:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int defaultvalue[] = {1,2};

int fun(int arg[] = defaultvalue)
{
    arg[0] += 1;
    return arg[0];
}

int main()
{
   cout << fun() << endl;
   cout << fun() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

but the result is still:

```
2
3
```

Moreover, when I print out the `defaultvalue`:

```
cout << defaultvalue[0] <<endl;
```

It turn out to be 3.

My question is, in the second example, should the function parameter be passed by value, so that change of `arg` will have no effect on `defaultvalue`?

Comment: As a function parameter type, `int*` and `int[]` are entirely identical.

Comment: `*arg` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 12):

> My question is, in the second example, should the function parameter be passed by value, so that change of arg will have no effect on defaultvalue?

No.

It is impossible to pass an array by value (thanks a lot, C!) so, as a "compromise" (read: design failure), `int[]` in a function parameter list actually means `int*`. So your two programs are identical. Even writing `int[5]` or `int[24]` or `int[999]` would actually mean `int*`. Ridiculous, isn't it?!

In C++ we prefer to use `std::array` for arrays: it's an array wrapper class, which has proper object semantics, including being copyable. You can pass those into a function by value just fine.

Indeed, `std::array` was primarily introduced for the very purpose of making these silly and surprising native array semantics obsolete.

Comment: Note to C programmers: You can get the same effect as `std::array` in C by defining a struct with an array member; you can then pass that struct type by value just fine.

Comment: There's another option: passing a *reference* to a fixed-size C array prevents pointer decay, but of course its preferable to use std::array.

Comment: @amon Note KerrekSB's solution (and OP's question) addresses the need to easily pass _copies_ of the array.

Comment: @amon: While true, that's rather the opposite of the OP's requirement ;)

Answer (score 3):

When we declare a function like this

```
int func(int* arg);
```

or this

```
int (func(int arg[])
```

They're technically the same. It's a matter of expressiveness. In the first case, it's *suggested* by the API author that the function should receive a pointer to a single value; whereas in the second case, it suggests that it wants an array (of some unspecified length, possibly ending in *nullptr*, for instance).

You could've also written

```
int (func(int arg[3])
```

which would again be technically identical, only it would hint to the API user that they're supposed to pass in an `int` array of at least 3 elements. The compiler doesn't enforce any of these added modifiers in these cases.

If you wanted to copy the array into the function (in a non-hacked way), you would first create a copy of it in the calling code, and then pass that one onwards. Or, as a better alternative, use `std::array` (as suggested by @LightnessRacesinOrbit).

Comment: What does "technically" mean? In which way are they *not* the same?

Comment: I've seen this "hint" catch out people who don't know that parameters `int[]`, `int[42]` and `int*` are the same, so they expect a compiler error if they pass an array of the wrong length, or even expect the array to be passed by value. So I prefer to say it like it is, and use `int*`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, in the non-technical sense, e.g. visually. But let's not get carried away with semantics.

Comment: @juanchopanza There is that approach, but you have to draw a line somewhere and not just say that whoever doesn't understand the language well enough gets to dictate coding conventions.

Comment: Kind of agreed. I see it more as a red flag that whoever wrote it didn't know the language well enough. More often than not, I've been right. But a lot of coding conventions I have seen are focused on people who don't understand the language well enough. Which, for C++, is most people.

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained, when you put 
`int arg[]` as a function parameter, whatever is inside those brackets doesn't really matter (you could even do int arg[5234234] and it would still work] since it won't change the fact that it's still just a plain int * pointer.

If you really want to make sure a function takes an array[] , its best to pass it like

```
template<size_t size>
void func (const int (&in_arr)[size])
{
    int modifyme_arr[100];
    memcpy(modifyme_arr, in_arr, size);

    //now you can work on your local copied array
}

int arr[100];
func(arr);
```

or if you want 100 elements exactly

```
    void func (const int (&arr)[100])
    {

    }

    func(arr);
```

These are the proper ways to pass a simple array, because it will give you the guaranty that what you are getting is an array, and not just a random int * pointer, which the function doesn't know the size of. Of course you can pass a "count" value, but what if you make a mistake and it's not the right one? then you get buffer overflow.

Comment: The OP wants the argument to be copied. This is literally the opposite.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: the `{1,2}` is implicitly size 2, whatever OP's intentions

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not exactly, since my  templated function was defined const from start (meaning it's protected from changes which is what the op wants), and it actually accepts int[] arrays (which i felt is what the op wants too) (of any size), i've added a body to the function to "copy" the arr values, altho that code was quite obvious